# View tabular data shows data but when I run the report as html on it the crosstab does not show the data

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I have a cognos report where in I am getting count distinct of a certain column and taking that data in a crosstab which is driven by a date prompt. I can see data for most of the dates but in some cases it does not show any data which should not be the case as the view tabular data of that particular query shows results.

Comment: Reproducing this from the samples and posting results of both "view tabular data" and the crosstab would be helpful.  You can use your actual data as long as you won't get in trouble for sharing company secrets or violating confidentiality.

Comment: Can you go to the query properties and see the generated SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The tabular result is a flat list whereas the Crosstab will create a 3 dimensional cube in the background.  When you run the tabular result you will see a message stating that what you see may not be what you get, given the summarization is disabled as well for the test.

For the missing crosstab cells,  if could be that the particular intersection between the rows and columns does not actually have any data.